# I want to save the previous value in formik and also the textfield name to my database

Tags: reactjs, formik

This is just your common formic form with error and a sumbmit method ,for updationg fields. But how do you save your previous answer (not new one when update) and the name of your textfield to another variable.When I press submit I want to save the name of the textfield and the old answer

```
   export default function Index ({ setFile, setMessageDisplay, ...props }) {
    let currentUser = AuthService.getCurrentUser();
    const [ notesId, setNotesId ] = useState();
    const [ releaseNotes, setReleaseNotes ] = useState({});
    const formRef = useRef();

    //Get todays date
    var today = new Date(),
        date = today.getFullYear() + '/' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + today.getDate();

    let url = `releaseNotes/all`;

    function fetchData () {
        Api(url, 'Get').then((data) => {
            setReleaseNotes(data[0]);
            setNotesId(data[0].id)
        });
    }


    //Get data on start
    useEffect(
        () => {
            fetchData();
        },
        [ url ]
    );
```

Updating and saving data

```
//Insert data /Update data
        async function submitForm (values) {
            // routine to send the request to the server
            const formData = new FormData();
            var postData = values;
            console.log(postData);
            formData.append(
                'releaseNotes',
                new Blob([ JSON.stringify(postData) ], {
                    type: 'application/json'
                })
            );
    
            //Send request
            return Api(`releaseNotes/updateReleaseNotes`, 'Post', formData);
        }
    
        return (
            <div>
```

Just Formik containing one field

```
<Formik
                    innerRef={formRef}
                    enableReinitialize={true}
                    initialValues={{
                        id: notesId,
                        notes: releaseNotes.notes || '',
                        lastUpdated: moment(date) || ''
                    }}
                    validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({    
                        verified: Yup.bool()
                    })}
                    onSubmit={async (values, { resetForm, setErrors, setStatus, setSubmitting }) => {
                        try {
                            //Call submitForm function
                            submitForm(values).then(() => {
                            
                            });
                        } catch (error) {
                            setStatus({ success: false });
                            setErrors({ submit: error.message });
                            setSubmitting(false);
                        }
                    }}>
                    {({
                        errors,
                        handleBlur,
                        handleChange,
                        handleSubmit,
                        isSubmitting,
                        setFieldTouched,
                        setFieldValue,
                        touched,
                        values
                    }) => (
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} {...props}>
                            <Card>
                                <CardContent>
                                    <Box mt={2}>
                                        <TextField
                                            fullWidth
                                            multiline
                                            label='Notes'
                                            name='notes'
                                            onChange={handleChange}
                                            value={values.notes}
                                            variant='outlined'
                                        />
                                    </Box>
                                    <Box mt={3} style={{ display: 'flex', float: 'right' }}>
                                        <Button variant='contained' color='secondary' type='submit' disabled={isSubmitting}>
                                            Save Changes to ReleaseNotes
                                        </Button>
                                    </Box>
                                </CardContent>
                            </Card>
                        </form>
                    )}
                </Formik>
```

This is the function I want to submit as well, something like this in mind

```
async function updateActivity (formName,oldValue) {

    const activityData={
        field:values.name,
        function:"Change",
        category:"Admin Change",
        userWhoMadeChange:currentUser.name,
        userChangeID:values.id,
        name:formName,
        oldValue:oldValue


    }
    const formData = new FormData();
    // routine to send the request to the server
    formData.append(
        'activityLog',
        new Blob([ JSON.stringify(activityData) ], {
            type: 'application/json'
        })
    );
    
    

    //Send request

    return Api(`activityLog/updateActivityLog`, 'Post', formData);
}
```

Comment: can you add your expected post request body which you need to send  ? .

Comment: @Shyam I did add it hope this is what you ment.

Comment: You want to add the initialValue as well in the request data. if yes, then how your final `formData`  will look ?

Comment: sorry trying to understand, so the initialvalues has the previous data ? How do you get the name of the field that changed when you upate? @Shyam

Comment: ok think I understand ,can use the value from the initial value , them link them by getting the name.(Just need to figure out if onchange on a field ,return the field name,any suggestion) @Shyam